# Vercel Middleware does not run on home page when using config/matcher

Tags: nextjs, vercel, vercel-middleware

I've got a multilingual JSS / Next.JS site. I am integrating Vercel Middleware and looking to exclude certain paths from the middleware without invoking middleware in the process of checking. As a refresher, here are the Vercel docs on how this can be done:

https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-middleware/middleware-api#config-object

In general, I'm seeing some unexpected behavior; primarily being that under some conditions, middleware does not run on the homepage even when I would expect it to, and this only seems to happen on my JSS site and not on a vanilla Next.JS site.

### Scenario 1 ✅

My middleware is:

```
async function middleware(req) {
  console.log('Middleware processing:', req.nextUrl.pathname);
}
```

When I load the home page I see this in my console:

```
Middleware processing: /
Middleware processing: /images/logo.svg
Middleware processing: /_next/static/chunks/webpack.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/chunks/main.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/chunks/pages/%5B%5B...path%5D%5D.js
Middleware processing: /_next/static/development/_devMiddlewareManifest.json
Middleware processing: /images/icon.svg
Middleware processing: /manifest.webmanifest
Middleware processing: /favicon.ico
```

### Scenario 2 ✅

Then I add an empty config above the middleware function:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [

  ]
};

async function middleware(req) {
  console.log('Middleware processing:', req.nextUrl.pathname);
}
```

I refresh the home page. I see no console logs. This seems to be expected, given that the matcher array is empty; so the middleware shouldn't run for *any* path.

### Scenario 3

I add a negative lookahead regex pattern to the config to match any path that does not start with any of the listed patterns.

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
'/((?!favicon.ico|_next/static|manifest.webmanifest|_next/image|images).*)'
  ]
};
```

I refresh the home page. I see nothing in the logs, meaning that the middleware didn't run even for the homepage path `/`. This is somewhat unexpected. The regex is supposed to allow the middleware to run on paths that don't match the given negative lookaheads. It should have matched the root `/`.

**On a vanilla Next.JS site, the middleware DOES run on the homepage, given this configuration.**

### Scenario 4

I explicitly add the home page path to the config array:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/',
    '/((?!favicon.ico|_next/static|manifest.webmanifest|_next/image|images).*)'
  ]
};
```

I refresh the homepage. I see:

```
Middleware processing: /
```

So, in my case, I need to explicitly add the home page path to have middleware run on the homepage when a negative lookahead is present. Where it gets interesting is that, going back to Scenario 3, **this is not necessary on a vanilla Next.JS site.**

Does anyone have a good explanation for this?